For visionOS app building, how is the native dinosaur app built?
In the Vision Pro, the dinosaur app that came with the device, I want to build something similar.
Huge screen with views inside that aren't video nor image, the content moves with eyesight.
WindowGroup (id: "loading"){
            popoutView()
        }
        .windowStyle(.volumetric)
        .defaultSize(width: 1000, height: 700, depth: 400)

so first question would be is that a volumetic window, or a immersive view?
doesn't look volumetric as it is still just a thin screen.
and how does entities in the view walk out of the view? I can control entities to move from a location to another in space by
model.position += SIMD3<Float>(0, 0, offsetZ.randomElement()

But if the position is behind the screen, then the entity is hidden (covered by screen)

Immersive, search the web for "portals"

Late note: WWDC24 session 10096, "Design interactive experiences for visionOS", goes into detail on how this demo was built. https://developer.apple.com/wwdc24/10096
